# Where do I place my lengthy code that prepares domain objects to be persisted in a Repository?

Tags: php, design-patterns, model-view-controller, zend-framework2, separation-of-concerns

I have some code like so:

```
/* Part of Controller::saveAction() */ 

//create new object instance
$item = new Item();

//populate the Item
$item->setDescription($description);
$item->setQuantity($quantity);
$item->setPrice($price);

//once we have a fully populated object, 
//send it to Repository pattern, 
//which saves it to persistent storage
$this->repository->saveItem($item);
```

Imagine several blocks like the above in a single funciton/method, and you will see my issue ... I am pretty happy with my `repository` line of code, but I do not know where to place all the "prep work" that is done before the call to `Repository`.

**Question:**

Where do I place the bulk of code that creates &populates the `Item` object instance?  It is cluttering up my Controller method and I can't seem to imagine another place to put it.

**Goal**

My goal is to find good structure/design rather than to purely reduce or minimize the number of "item preparation" lines.

Depending on Controller, I have roughly 5-7 `Item` instances that each have 10-16 lines of code creating and populating the instances.

Comment: Is it just the amount of lines of code you are concerned about? If `Item` could be passed constructor arguments that would make it neater. Alternatively, make the set methods chainable.

Comment: For amount of code, not really, I am more interested in proper structure.  But I do roughly have over 100 lines of code in a single method, that "create, polish, and prepare" the object for saving.  And a few lines of code that actually save the objects.  As far as passing `Item` via Constructor ... what calling code construct will be in charge of preparing the objects?  Are you suggesting I use a something like a `ControllerFactory` to populate `Controller`'s with the `Items` via constructor?  I have 7 individual `Items` to be saved in a method, the number varies from Controller to Controller

Comment: I think @Chris means to have an Item `___construct()` method to set the properties and do `$item = new Item($description, $quantity, $price);`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes, that is what I meant. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned about the proper way of achieving
so.. how about using delegators and splitting the controller (blocks) into delegators? It terms of terminology it would be the Facade [Adapter]

add the following to ./module/MyModule/config/module.config.php:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'MyModule\CreateController' => 'MyModule\Controller\MyController',
        'MyModule\ReadController' => 'MyModule\Controller\MyController',
    ),
    'delegators' => array(
        'MyModule\CreateController' => array(
            'MyModule\Controller\Delegator\CreateItemDelegatorFactory'
        ),
        'MyModule\ReadController' => array(
            'MyModule\Controller\Delegator\ReadItemDelegatorFactory'
        ),
    ),
),
'form_elements' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'item_create' => 'MyModule\Form\CreateForm',
    ),
),
```

Create Delegator loads form, populates it, validates and tries to save teh data

./module/MyModule/src/MyModule/Controller/Delegator/CreateItemDelegatorFactory.php:

```
namespace MyModule\Controller\Delegator;

use Zend\ServiceManager\DelegatorFactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use MyModule\Entity\Item as Entity;

/**
 *  Class loads the form, checks if form been posted and if is valid.
 *  If form is valid it tries to save the item with repository service
 *  Class sets the Form per controller, such solution keeps form      
 *  validation messages
 */
class CreateItemDelegatorFactory implements DelegatorFactoryInterface
{
   /**
    * Determines name of the form to be loaded with formElementManager
    * 
    * @var string
    */
   private $form_name = "item_create";

   /**
    * Name of repository service. It may be database, api or other
    *
    * @var string
    */
   private $service_repository_name = "service.repository";

   public function createDelegatorWithName(
        ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator,
        $name,
        $requestedName,
        $callback
    ) {
        // assign serviceManager locally
        $parentLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        // assign services locally
        $routerService = $parentLocator->get('router');
        $requestService = $parentLocator->get('request');
        // get repository service
        $repositoryService = $parentLocator->get($this->service_repository_name);

        // read the CreateForm with formElementManager and bind the Entity
        $callback->setForm(
             $parentLocator->get('FormElementManager')->get($this->form_name)
        );
        $entity = new Entity;
        $callback->getForm($this->form_name)->bind($entity);

        // check if data been posted   
        if($requestService->isPost()) {
            $postData = $requestService->getPost($this->form_name);
            $callback->getForm($this->form_name)->setData($postData);
            // validate form
            if($callback->getForm($this->form_name)->isValid()) {
                // form is valid
                $repositoryService->saveItem($entity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With above Delegator your controller (MyModule\Controller\MyController) would need the additional property and two methods:

```
/**
 * Holds the form object
 * @var object
 */
private $form

public function setForm($form=null)
{
    $this->form = $form;
    return $this;
}

public function getForm()
{
    return $this->form;
}
```

./module/MyModule/src/MyModule/Controller/Delegator/ReadItemDelegatorFactory.php:

```
namespace MyModule\Controller\Delegator;

use Zend\ServiceManager\DelegatorFactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use MyModule\Entity\Item as Entity;

/**
 * Creates Delegator which tries read item's id from the (segment type) route
 * and read the Item from the repository service
 *
 */
class ReadItemDelegatorFactory implements DelegatorFactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Item's ID from route
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $route_identifier = "item_id";

    /**
     * Name of repository service. It may be database, api or other
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $service_repository_name = "service.repository";

    public function createDelegatorWithName(
        ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator,
        $name,
        $requestedName,
        $callback
    ) {
        // assign serviceManager locally
        $parentLocator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        // assign services locally
        $routerService = $parentLocator->get('router');
        $requestService = $parentLocator->get('request');
        // get repository service
        $repositoryService = $parentLocator->get($this->service_repository_name);
        // get the router match and the item_id
        $routerMatch = $routerService->match($requestService);
        $itemId = $routerMatch->getParam($this->route_identifier);
        // set the data for the target controller
        $callback->setItem($repositoryService->readItem($itemId));

        return $callback;
    }
```

With above Delegator your controller (MyModule\Controller\MyController) would need the additional property and method:

```
/**
 * Holds the Item object
 * @var object \MyModule\Entity\Item
 */
private $item

public function setItem($item=null)
{
    $this->item = $item;
    return $this;
}
```

Such a way of controller's use helps for the code to stay DRY and seems to be possible to control the flow. Delegators are being loaded as LIFO, so it is possiblt to preconfigure the controller ($callback) before passing it to another Delegator.

If the ReadController reads the item and the CreateController loads the form it is a short way for UpdateItemDelegator to handle the Item Update task.

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'MyModule\UpdateController' => 'MyModule\Controller\MyController',
    'delegators' => array(
        'MyModule\ReadController' => array(
            'MyModule\Controller\Delegator\UpdateItemDelegatorFactory',
            'MyModule\Controller\Delegator\CreateItemDelegatorFactory',
            'MyModule\Controller\Delegator\ReadItemDelegatorFactory'
        ),
    ),
),
```

Delegators explained:
http://ocramius.github.io/blog/zend-framework-2-delegator-factories-explained/

Edit:

Controller prepared for both Delegators (Create and Read) would look like:

```
namespace MyModule\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class CreateController extends AbstractActionController
{
    /**
     * Holds the Item object
     * @var object \MyModule\Entity\Item
     */
    private $item

    /**
     * Holds the form object
     * @var mixed null|object
     */
    private $form;

     /**
      * Item's details. It reads item by the `item_id` which is param set in route with same name
      * @return \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel
      */
     public function readAction()
     {
         $v = new ViewModel();
         // set item, access it in template as `$this->item`
         $v->setVariable('item',$this->getItem());

         return $v;
     }

     /**
      * The Form preconfigured with CreateItemDelegatorFactory should be av. in template as `$this->form`
      * @return \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel
      */
     public function createAction()
     {
         $v = new ViewModel();
         // set form, access the in template as `$this->form`
         $v->setVariable('form',$this->getForm());

         return $v;
     }

    /**
     * Sets the Item object
     * @var $item \MyModule\Entity\Item
     * @return $this
     */
     public function setItem($item=null)
     {
         $this->item = $item;
         return $this;
     }

     /**
     * Gets the Item object
     * @return object \MyModule\Entity\Item
     */
     public function getItem()
     {
        return $this->item;
     }

     public function setForm($form=null)
     {
        $this->form = $form;
        return $this;
     }

     /**
      * Returns form defined in config and CreateItemDelegatorFactory::form_name
      * @return \Zend\Form\Form
      */
     public function getForm()
     {
         return $this->form;
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks.  Could you give an example of what the code would be like inside controller?  i.e. `Controller::action(){ .... }`?
That part was unclear to me

Answer (score 0):

**Observation**

Individual values like `$description, $quantity, $price` must come from somewhere.  It could be GET, POST, SESSION, COOKIES, or database or external methods.  Let's call it `$_SOMEWHERE` for clarity.  We then get:

```
$description = $_SOMEWHERE['description'];
$quantity = $_SOMEWHERE['quantity'];
$price = $_SOMEWHERE['price'];
```

Define an Input&Preparation class that does the work for you and returns the prepared `Item`.

```
class AcquireItem
{
    function getItem()
    {
        $item = new Item();

        $item->setDescription($_SOMEWHERE['description']);
        $item->setQuantity($_SOMEWHERE['quantity']);
        $item->setPrice($_SOMEWHERE['price']);

        return $item;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$item = (new AcquireItem())->getItem();
$this->repository->saveItem($item);
```

Controller becomes shorter, by effectively "stuffing away" the bulky clutter code into a class that is concerned with reading and preparing input, and decluttering the controller.  The code has to exist somewhere, but might as well be out of view, and elsewhere.

For different types of `Item`, you can vary the method, i.e. `getItemA()`, `getItemB()`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally believe that create-methods should go into the repository.
That is because I would expect the repositories to contain all CRUD (create, read, update, delete) methods.

It's just my personal thought on this topic...